# extract date from string in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

How can I extract date from such strings in excel?

```
John8/11/12
Jackson09/11/2013
```

Desired result:

```
John     8/11/12
Jackson  09/11/2013
```

Can I do this using only excel formula using excel functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract name:

```
=LEFT(A1, MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},1)),0)-1)
```

To extract date:

```
=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},1)),0)+1)
```

Note : both must be entered as an array formula `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`

Answer (score 3):

Use `=LEFT(A1,MIN(FIND(0,SUBSTITUTE(A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},0)&0))-1)` in the column directly to the right of the string and `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,"")` as the following column... Then copy the formula down.

[image: first]

[image: second]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use regular expressions in order to achieve this. Im not very familiar with excel but heres a link that might help http://www.dzone.com/snippets/regular-expressions-excel-2007

Answer (score 0):

Excel Function:

```
Function FindNumeric( pvsString As String ) As Integer
    Dim viPosition As Integer
    Dim viFoundAt As Integer
    viFoundAt = 0
    For viPosition = 1 To Len(pvsString)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(pvsString, viPosition, 1)) Then
            viFoundAt = viPosition
            Exit For
        End If 
    Next viPosition
End Function
```

Then in your 
In your worksheet cell:

For Name: `=Mid( A1, 1, FindNumeric(A1)-1)`

For Date: `=Mid( A1, FindNumeric(A1), 10)`